# git clone shows "Initialized empty Git repository in xxxxxxxxx(my directory)"

Tags: git, github

I changed my project repository to private, and when I tried to pull from github it failed. Then I deleted everything in my directory and tried to clone a new repository to my computer, but it also failed.

I used "git clone https://github.com/username/myrepo.git" and it said:

**Initialized empty Git repository in xxxxx/myrepo/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/username/myrepo.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed**

Then I also tried "git clone https://username@github.com/username/myrepo.git"
and it said:

**Initialized empty Git repository in xxxx/myrepo/.git/**

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you create a public repository, do you have the same problem?

Comment: @mkrufky I just cloned one of my public repository. There's no problem.

Comment: Does it ask you for a username and password when you clone your private repository via https?  If you're not providing a username & password, perhaps that's why this isn't working.  I recommend trying the clone over ssh instead.

Comment: @mkrufky No, it directly throws me an error

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning using the ssh url instead:

```
git clone git@github.com:username/myrepo.git
```

Comment: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

Error 403 means permission denied. You need to set up your public key on github. Instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/